# appending values to Julia Dict using for loop

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, julia

I have 3 dataframes and wanted to append some strings based on the if else conditions

```
df1 = DataFrame(p1 = [1, 2, 3],p2 = [1,2,3])
df2 = DataFrame(q1 = [1, 2, 3 ],q2 = [3,7,9])
df3 = DataFrame(r1 = [0,1],r2 = [1,1])
datas = Dict()
for data1 in eachrow(df1)
    for data2 in eachrow(df2)
        for data3 in eachrow(df3)

            if data1[1]==data2[1]==data3[1]
                datas[data1[1]]="data1[2]"*"data1[2]"*"data3[2]"

            elseif data1[1]==data2[1]!=data3[1]
                datas[data1[1]]="data1[2]"*"data2[2]"

            elseif  data1[1]==data3[1]!=data2[1]
                datas[data1[1]]="data1[2]"*"data2[2]"

            elseif data2[1]!=data3[1]!=data1[1]
                datas[data2[1]]="data2[2]"*"data3[2]"

            elseif data1[1]!=data3[1]!=data2[1]
                datas[data1[1]]="data1[2]"
                datas[data2[1]]="data2[2]"
                datas[data3[1]]="data3[2]"
        
            end 
        end           
    end 
end
```

But my loop overwriting the existing values in  the Dict
There can be case that df3 can be zero.

As I am not sound enough to append the values to dictionary using !haskey.

It would be really helpful if some one guide with a solution

Comment: It's not at all clear what you expect the datas dictionary to be in the end.  You could first initialize your dictionary elements to be empty lists and then append to those lists.

Comment: This is a cross post from Julia Discourse: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/iterating-through-rows-in-julia-dataframe/84475/15 - as said there (and in the comment above) it is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve, so it's not possible to answer your question.

Comment: As a lucky guess, when you write `datas[data1[1]]="data1[2]"*"data1[2]"*"data3[2]"`, don't you mean instead: `datas[data1[1]]="$(data1[2]) $(data1[2]) $(data3[2])"` ? That is put the value of `data1[2]` in your string instead of just writing the letters "data1[2]" ?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, the question as it stands is unanswerable in my view. Given how unclear the requirements are, it makes more sense to continue discussion on Discourse, as SO is not the right venue for these types of iterative questions.

To provide an answer here though I'll copy a slightly edited version of my last Discourse post, which addresses the main point in your question ("how to append to a dictionary"):

I understand that you are trying to append something to your dictionary, whereas your current code overwrites the keys. Consider:

```
julia> d = Dict(1 => "a")
Dict{Int64, String} with 1 entry:
  1 => "a"

julia> d[1] = "b"
"b"

julia> d
Dict{Int64, String} with 1 entry:
  1 => "b"
```

If you want to append, you need to get the item first:

```
julia> d[1] = d[1] * "c"
"bc"

julia> d
Dict{Int64, String} with 1 entry:
  1 => "bc"
```

But what if the item doesn't exist yet?

```
julia> d[2] = d[2] * "d"
ERROR: KeyError: key 2 not found
```

That's what `get` is for, here you can supply a default value that will be returned if the key doesn't exist. In your case it's useful to return an empty string to append to:

```
julia> d[2] = get(d, 2, "") * "d"
"d"

julia> d
Dict{Int64, String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "d"
  1 => "bc"
```

So your code could look something like this:

```
using DataFrames
df1=DataFrame(p1 = [1, 2, 3], p2 = [1, 2, 3])
df2=DataFrame(q1 = [1, 2, 3], q2 = [3, 7, 9])
df3=DataFrame(r1 = [0, 1], r2 = [1, 1])
datas = Dict()

for data1 in eachrow(df1)
    for data2 in eachrow(df2)
        for data3 in eachrow(df3)

            v1, v2, v3 = data1[1], data2[1], data3[1]
            s1, s2, s3 = string.(data1[2], data2[2], data3[2])

            if v1 == v2 == v3
                datas[v1] = get(datas, v1, "") * s1 * s2 * s3
            elseif v1 == v2 != v3
                datas[v1] = get(datas, v1, "") * s1 * s2
            elseif  v1 == v3 != v2 
                datas[v1] = get(datas, v1, "") * s1 * s2
            elseif v2 != v3 != v1
                datas[v2] = get(datas, v2, "") * s2 * s3
            elseif v1 != v3 != v2 
                datas[v1] = get(datas, v1, "") * s1 
                datas[v2] = get(datas, v2, "") * s2
                datas[v3] = get(datas, v3, "") * s3
            end 
        end           
    end 
end
```